# php - How get efficiently the array which is contained in a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm on laravel. In my controller, i get an array stored in a hidden field.
The array comes into a string

```
'[1,2]'
```

How i can get the php array from this string? And the array items must be the intenger value.

```
[1,2]
```

Of course, have in mind various ways to achieve this, but i want the best.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way in this case would be `json_decode()`:

```
$string = '[1,2]';
$array = json_decode($string, true);

var_dump($array);

// Output:
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode() or json_decode()` functions

Comment: But the "[" and the "]" stay included. For example: "[ 1 , 2 , 3 ]"
$newArray = explode (',', $arr);
$newArray is [ [1 , 2 , 3] ]